# Sencha touch selectfield Placeholder

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

How can i add a selectfield placeHolder in sencha touch..

here is my code

```
{
                        xtype: 'selectfield',
                        label: 'Subclient',
                        itemId: 'subclient',
                        name: 'subclient',
                        labelWrap:'true',
                        autoSelect:'false',
                        placeHolder:'Select',
                        required:true,

                        //labelWidth: '40%',

                        options: [
                            {text: 'Standard Sale', value: 'Standard Sale'},
                            {text: 'Short Sale',  value: 'Bank of America'},
                            {text: 'REO',  value: 'REO'}
                        ]
                    },
```

Here the placeholder is not visible..i can only managed to see the first text value option in da list.

i tried by adding

```
 {text: 'Select a Client', value: 'Select'},
```

As the first option but, in this case i cannot able to validate it using my model validation.. 
Any one plz help me to solve this issue ..your help is much appreciated ..Thanks in Advance

Comment: what do you mean by "the placeholder is not visible"? Your selectfield just displayed the first option instead of the placeHolder or ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes from around the `false` for the `autoSelect` property (and ALL boolean config options):

```
{
    xtype: 'selectfield',
    label: 'Subclient',
    itemId: 'subclient',
    name: 'subclient',
    labelWrap: true,
    autoSelect: false,
    placeHolder: 'Select',
    required: true,

    options: [
        {text: 'Standard Sale', value: 'Standard Sale'},
        {text: 'Short Sale',  value: 'Bank of America'},
        {text: 'REO',  value: 'REO'}
    ]
```

},

Comment: Thank you so much...Thank you so much for your help. Now it working fine..But a small issue..now i can see placeholder value at the starting on the page..but i cannot select the first option..when i select the first option in the list its still showing the placeholder value..

Comment: I see this issue, and I'm not sure what the problem is.  It seems to me like a bug in the framework.  You could try posting it here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?92-Sencha-Touch-2.x-Bugs